# Multiple graphs in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to generate a report in `R` and `knitr`. I have most of the document ready and working.  But in one section of the document I need to generate a number of plots.  However, the exact number of plot varies from report to report.  It is determined by a `list` generated by the `R` part of the code.  The number of elements of this list are not constant.  Is there a way to do this in `knitr`.

For example, I am generating a list of graphs, say `l`, such that

```
l <- c()
l <- c(l, p) # where p is a ggplot graph
l <- c(l, p2) # where p2 is another ggplot graph
```

However, at the end of the processing `length(l)` is variable.  How can I use `knitr` to plot all of these graphs in the document?

Answer (score 2):

Just print the list:

````
```{r}
l
```
````

This will generate all the plots in the list. However, this will put rather ugly list index numbers in the document. You can therefore also use the following, which omits this:

````
```{r}
invisible(lapply(l, plot))
```
````

Comment: Oh! Okay, let me try this.  If this works, my next question would be how do I get each graph its own caption/label etc?

Comment: @Sam Very good question, no idea. I can’t get labels to work at all, actually (never used them).

Comment: Hi @Konrad Rudolph, this did not work.  It only plots the last plot.